# Python Loop For (Error in printing final exit program)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, break

1. I need to run a code using 'loop for' 20 times.
2. If there is no user input (enter), my code should print "Exit program~~" and break the loop.
3. If the code is ran 20 times already, the code should print "Exit program~~" AFTER printing the last (2oth) input number.
4. I need '+/- number' to be printed after every time user inputs the number.
5. The output must be printed with str.format()

Output should be like this:

Enter the number : 0

+0 : zero

Enter the number : 17

+17 : positive

Enter the number : -8

-8 : negative

Enter the number:

Exit program~~

My problem:
My code works, but I can't figure out how to print "Exit program~~" after I input numbers 20 times. *But "Exit program~~" works when I exit before inputting all 20 times.

My code:

```
sign = ['positive', 'negative', 'zero']

for i in range(20):
    num = input('Enter the number : ')
    if num == '':
        print('{}'.format('Exit program~~'))
        break
    else:
        if int(num) > 0:
            print('{:+.0f} : {}'.format(int(num), sign[0]))
        else:
            if int(num) < 0:
                print('{:-.0f} : {}'.format(int(num), sign[1]))
            else:
                print('{:+.0f} : {}'.format(int(num), sign[2]))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Perhaps my understanding of your problem is faulty, but couldn't you just add the print Exit program after the loop?

Comment: There's no need to use `format()` when you're just printing a single string. `'{}'.format('Exit program~~')` should just be `'Exit program~~'`

Comment: @jrylim ewong gave a suggestion to fix the problem. Did you try it?

Comment: The Exit program was printed double when I did that, I fixed it by removing the print Exit program above the break. Thanks! @ewong

Comment: I tried and the Exit program was printed double. But I managed to fix it thanks to Aproximate Knowledge's help! @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @jrylim ah yes.  My mistake.  I hadn't considered that condition that once it breaks, it also prints a message.  My bad.  Sorry.

Comment: Alright I thought it was kind of unnecessary, too. Thanks for the advice! @Barmar

Comment: Thanks, though. I learned a lot! @ewong

Comment: @jrylim as am I..  everyday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sign = ['positive', 'negative', 'zero']

for i in range(20):
    num = input('Enter the number : ')
    if num == '':
        break
    else:
        if int(num) > 0:
            print('{:+.0f} : {}'.format(int(num), sign[0]))
        else:
            if int(num) < 0:
                print('{:-.0f} : {}'.format(int(num), sign[1]))
            else:
                print('{:+.0f} : {}'.format(int(num), sign[2]))

print('{}'.format('Exit program~~'))
```

Have you considered something like this? Just removing the print for the case where nothing is entered and just having one print for anytime the loop is exited.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
print('Exit program~~')
```

right after the for loop. So after the for loop runs 20 times, Exit program~~ will be printed.

Comment: It made Exit program printed double,, but thanks a lot!